# OpenGL: Cannot not render a triangle

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

After writing the code and running it, nothing worked. I managed to fill the background but nothing else.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glad\glad.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>

const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;

const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 450 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
"}\0";

const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 450 core\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
    "FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
"}\0";

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);

int main()
{
    // Initializes GLFW and passes window hints 
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 5);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // Creates GLFWwindow called window
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "LearningOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Check if GLAD is initialized
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    float vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
    };

    int success;
    char infoLog[512];


    // Creating Vertex Shader Object
    unsigned int vertexShader;
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    // Creating Fragment Shader Object
    unsigned int fragmentShader;
    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    // Shader program
    unsigned int shaderProgram;
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();

    // Attatching both shaders to the program and then linking them
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    // Interpreting vertex data 
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // Generating a Vertex Array Object
    unsigned int VAO;
    unsigned int VBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Size of rendering window 
    glViewport(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback); 

    // While window is open
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Finally
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    // If loop is exited, terminate all allocated resources and close the program
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// Frame buffer function that resizes the viewport when the window gets resized
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow * window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Comment: What's your glad generation string/URL?  `--profile="core" --api="gl=4.5" --generator="c" --spec="gl" --no-loader --extensions=""`/http://glad.dav1d.de/#profile=core&language=c&specification=gl&api=gl%3D4.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to enable or set vertex attribute pointers before you have a VAO bound.  Won't do anything useful in a Core context.

Bind a VAO *then* enable/set attributes:

```
unsigned int VBO;
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Generating a Vertex Array Object
unsigned int VAO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glBindVertexArray( VAO );

// Interpreting vertex data 
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
```

Answer (score 4):

I noticed a few errors or problems with your code: The first apparent error is that after your call to:

> ```
> glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
> ```

You should be calling:

> ```
> glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback( window, framebuffer_size_callback );
> ```

This should be done after making the window the current context and before all of your `OpenGL` stuff.

---

The second problem that I see is within the setup of your `VAO` & `VBO` after reading in the information from your shaders and that is you have some things in an improper order and you are even missing a call or two from this section of your code:

> ```
> // Interpreting vertex data 
> glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
> glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
>
> // Generating a Vertex Array Object
> unsigned int VAO;
> unsigned int VBO;
> glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
> glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
> glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
> glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
>
> // Size of rendering window 
> glViewport(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
> glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
> ```

- First, you should be creating and initializing your `VBO` & `VAO` before calling `glVertexAttribPointer()` & `glEnableVertexAtrribArray()`. Think of this from the perspective of the API - Library. How can I enable a pointer to something that doesn't yet exist in memory?
- Second, you are missing a call to `glBindVertexArray(VAO);` This should be after you generate your `VAO` & `VBO`.
- Third, the last two lines of code I already explained about the function `glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback()` and where it should be placed; but for this part I'll explain why. This is the function that sets up your viewport as it is a call back type of function. After you set the window to being the current context; this is where you want to tell OpenGL the size of your viewport or window so that it knows the `Screen Size` to work with in translating all of the vertex data into screen space coordinates. By fixing this you won't have to make the call to `glViewport()` independently; as this is what the call back function does for you.

This section of code should look like this:

```
unsigned int VBO, VAO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
// bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s), and then configure vertex attributes(s).
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

// note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the vertex attribute's bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); 

// You can unbind the VAO afterwards so other VAO calls won't accidentally modify this VAO, but this rarely happens. Modifying other
// VAOs requires a call to glBindVertexArray anyways so we generally don't unbind VAOs (nor VBOs) when it's not directly necessary.
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

---

The last thing that I see is in your while loop for rending and after the loop as you have:

> ```
> // While window is open
> while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
> {
>    // Finally
>    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
>    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
>    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
>    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
>    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
>
>    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
>    glfwPollEvents();
> }
> // If loop is exited, terminate all allocated resources and close the program
> glfwTerminate();
> return 0;
> ```

I am seeing two concerns here:

> First, the order of using the program and binding the vertex arrays are backwards, they should be:
>
> ```
> glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
> glBindVertexArray(VAO);
> ```
>
> Second after your while loop and before the `glfwTerimate()` call you should be deleting your vertex array and buffers
>
> ```
> glDeleteVertexArrays( 1, &VAO );
> glDeleteBuffers( 1, &VBO );
> ```

---

If these simple corrections do not fix your problem there is one other thing that you might be able to try. You can try changing the version of `OpenGL` from `4.5` to `3.3` since the versions of their `GLSL Shader` languages are slightly different.

If this doesn't work, then it could be something within how you setup the external libraries that you are using.

---

**Summary**

You first have to set the view port before trying to setup any of the vertex data. Next, you have to set up your `VAO` & `VBO` information before you can make a call to `glVertexAtrribPointer()` & `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` and don't forget to make a call to `glBindVertexArray(VAO)` after the calls to generate them. After all of the initialization is in proper order then when using it in the render loop you should make a call to `glUseProgram` before `glBindVertexArray`. Finally after your render loop you should make the appropriate calls to delete your vertex arrays and buffers. If these fail, then you can try changing the version of `OpenGl - GLSL` and check the setup of all external libraries that are being used.

Comment: This is a great writeup and you made plenty of good points. I feel sorry that you didn't get the checkmark.